# Using-Pattern in a while loop

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've got a little stuck with a small problem here:
I use serialport communications - all my functions for comm. are wrapped into my own serialport class.
Instances of that class are supposed to only be used in the

```
 using(Serport port = new Serport(...)){}
```

to assure, that Dispose() is called after the operation.

Now this is no problem with one time calls, but I can't think of a way for this:
I have a function that is supposed to be called via a while loop for permanently refreshing via comport until the user interrupts (the function is designed to reset a timer itself every time it's called and time out when not called anymore). 
Now this operation is quite time-critical and cannot be opening and closing the serialport every time it gets called. So using the using pattern from up there inside that function won't work ( or will it ?)
The only way to realize this I can think of is to place the using(){} around the while loop - I'd like to avoid that though since it would mix up my code that is clearly built in a way, that comport access is handled low level and to the real app only simple functions that do all the work are availible...

Do you guys see any alternative? Is there a way to terminate the using pattern by hand? Just calling Dispose() by hand in my timeout-timer won't work since it won't be called if I get an exception - and I have to be sure that Dispose() gets called, so the serialport stay manageable...

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If your concern is repeatedly creating and disposing of the serial port connection (and this is why you don't want to use the `using` statement from within the function), why would you be any better off calling `Dispose` by hand?

Comment: Because I could call Dispose() by hand from the .Elapsed-Event of the timeout timer which is only reached when the function isn't called anymore. But if I call by Hand I don't have the assurance of the using(){} directive, that Dispose() will be called even if I get an exception ( e.g. ReadTimeout or something like that).

Comment: Alright, so that's exactly why a code sample would help tremendously. I can understand and process code much easier than I can conceptualize your design in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `using` statement for an IDisposable:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> The using statement ensures that
>   Dispose is called even if an exception
>   occurs while you are calling methods
>   on the object. You can achieve the
>   same result by putting the object
>   inside a try block and then calling
>   Dispose in a finally block; in fact,
>   this is how the using statement is
>   translated by the compiler. The code
>   example earlier expands to the
>   following code at compile time (note
>   the extra curly braces to create the
>   limited scope for the object):
>
> ```
> {
>   Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
>   try
>   {
>     byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
>   }
>   finally
>   {
>     if (font1 != null)
>       ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
>   }
> }
> ```

You can either make sure that your exception handling *does* call Dispose, or you can for example make some outer Parent class inherit from IDisposable:

```
void Parent.Dispose()
{
  if (port != null)
  {
    port.Dispose();
  }
}
```

and wrap the creation of the Parent object in the `using` statement, and let *it* worry about calling Dispose on the Serport.

Comment: Thanks a lot - sometimes the solution can be so damn easy and one thinks much to complicated^^ solved it now by including port.Dispose() inside the finally{} in my timeouttimer.Elapsed Event - always gets called that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your serial port open for the whole duration of the session, because if you constantly open/close it, you will surely lose data and break any protocol you want over it.

If you want to share your serial comm among several other objects, that's whole different story.

So, try to open it once, close and dispose it when really won't be needed any more.

Conclusion: using 'using' isn't much practical here.

Comment: I've done exactly that before - the problem is that SerialPort.Close() of .NET isn't really very reliable - get one read exception or whatever and it's not closed properly and I end up with a UnauthorizedAccessException next time I try to open the port. For that cause using the using(){} directive is wonderful since it assures that Dispose() is called in any case and my port is definitly freed up after use. That's why I've been restructuring my prog to only use using(){} but with this specific function I've hit a big problem... :)

Comment: Well. . . dispose will call close and free any resources associated with serial port, but won't do any magic for you. Use reflector and look into its source and you'll see that there isn't much code that will magically free your port in a way that close is unable to do.